# Displaying SVG in Flex 4

Tags: svg, flex4

It seems like SVG has be "deprecated" in Flex 4 in favor of Adobe's FXG. What can I do if I have a bunch of SVG graphics that I want to keep using. Is there something reliable to convert SVG to FXG? Are they in feature parity? Is there a converter out there that won't cost me $1500?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inkscape also [exports fxg](https://bugs.launchpad.net/inkscape/+bug/625140) now (see comments #24 and #42), but with [some limitations](http://wiki.inkscape.org/wiki/index.php/SpecFXGExport).

It uses simple XSLT as extension, so you can write simple script in any language that supports XML transformations to produce FXG from your SVG's.

Answer (score 1):

Actually if you are programming in flex 4, check out the spark path primitive. For path data it uses a string that has the same syntax as an svg path. You just have to parse it out but actionscript fully supports regular expressions so it shouldn't be too hard to load an svg as a text/xml file with urlrequest and parse out the path data for your primitives.
http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/primitives/Path.html

Path Objects only support transforms on their entire path so if you want to manipulate path data in real time you will just have to parse the data in a data structure and convert to a string for display.

It used to be that if you wanted to display an svg path with the actionscript 3.0 graphics library you would have to approximate the cubic berzier with quadratic berziers upon display but the spark primitive does do away with that by accepting path data in cubic form-- although even the spark primitives, when they draw themselves out, do seem to be approximations that are reaaallly close.

Comment: Paths are just one type of graphical element... I have a complete logo rendering in SVG and I want to display it. Can this be done with the method you describe?

Answer (score 1):

Depends how much work you want to do to interpret the svg data. If you want to do things like implement styles, masks/clipping and blur effects, the functionality is there in flex 4 with path and all of it's properties but implementing it from the data is going to require work.

Most of the svg graphical elements(shapes and text) can be converted to path data in programs like inkscape. Even so, actionscript has draw method geomitries that most likely support the basic shapes.

Also transforms on groups of elements will have to be parsed if you want to use that as well, or you can just not use groups, they are rather pointless when you aren't manipulating them.